# For every thousand units entered in one variable subtract 1 from another variable?

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that takes input of degrees and altitude and then returns what state the water is in. so -55 and below it is solid.

Boiling water is affected by the altitude so for every 1000ft of altitude the boiling point lowers 1 degree.

I have no idea how to express that in code. below is the code that I have so far. I know there are probably easier ways of writing this, but I have stick with switch and/or if statements.

```
public class Water 
{

   private final double temperature;
   private final String degrees;
   private final int altitude;
   private final String units;

   public Water(double temp, String deg, int alt, String unitType)
   {
       temperature = temp;
       degrees = deg;
       altitude = alt;
       units = unitType;
   }

   public String getState()
   {

    switch (degrees) 
    {
           case "F":
               if (temperature > -55 && temperature < 212)
               {
                   System.out.println("The water is liquid.");
               }
               else if (temperature <= -55)
               {
                   System.out.println("The water is solid.");
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("The water is gaseous.");
               }     break;
           case "C":
               if (temperature > -48 && temperature < 99.98)
               {
                   System.out.println("The water is liquid");
               }
               else if (temperature <= -48)
               {
                   System.out.println("The water is solid.");
               }
               else
               {
                   System.out.println("The water is gaseous.");
               }   break;
           default:
               System.out.println("Error: Degrees must be in either C (celcius) or F (farenheit).");
               break;
    }       


       return temperature + degrees;
   }


}
```

Comment: Doesn't water freeze at 0c?

Comment: water can be water or ice at 0C

Comment: Hint: Assume the boiling point varies linearly with altitude for purposes of the program, and write an equation in code that calculates the boiling point at any altitude.

Comment: I corrected the freezing point issue. I don't know what I was thinking there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest, cleanest way to do this would be to have a helper method `calculateBoilingPoint` that would maybe take the altitude and temperature and return the appropriate boiling point.

based on the code you posted, you could probably even just do that calculation once and then store that value in your class. Then, instead of your checks being

```
else if (temperature <= -55)
```

they would change to

```
else if (temperature <= boilingPoint)
```

or something similar