# calculating the matter state of water using if statements?

Tags: java

I need to calculate the state of water solid, liquid or gas by taking user input of the temperature in either Celsius or Farenheit and the altitude in either feet or Meters.

When I try and run the program it always says the water is gaseous. I can't seem to figure out what I am missing. or doing wrong.

```
public class Water 
{

   private final double temperature;
   private final String degrees;
   private final int altitude;
   private final String units;
   private final double bpFeet;
   private final double bpMeters;
   private String waterState;


   public Water(double temp, String deg, int alt, String unitType)
   {
       temperature = temp;
       degrees = deg;
       altitude = alt;
       units = unitType;
       bpFeet = temperature - (altitude * 0.001); //boiling point given an altitude in feet
       bpMeters = temperature - (altitude * 0.01); //boiling point given an altitude in meters
   }

   public String getState()
   {

        if (degrees.equals("F"))
        {
                   if (units.equals("Ft"))
                   {
                       if (temperature >= bpFeet)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is gaseous.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else if (temperature > 32 && temperature < bpFeet)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is liquid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is solid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                   }

                   else if (units.equals("M"))
                   {
                       if (temperature <= bpMeters)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is solid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else if (temperature > 32 && temperature < bpMeters)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is liquid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else 
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is solid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       System.out.println("Error: must enter FT (feet) or M (meters)");
                   }
        }

        else if (degrees.equals("C"))
        {
                   if (units.equals("Ft"))
                   {
                       if (temperature >= bpFeet)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is gaseous.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else if (temperature > 0 && temperature < bpFeet)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is liquid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is solid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                   }

                   else if (units.equals("M"))
                   {
                       if (temperature <= bpMeters)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is solid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else if (temperature > 0 && temperature < bpMeters)
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is liquid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                       else 
                       {
                           waterState = "The water is solid.";
                           System.out.println(waterState);
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       System.out.println("Error: must enter FT (feet) or M (meters)");
                   }
       }

       else
       {
           System.out.println("Error: must enter C (centigrade) or F (farenheit)");
       }



           return temperature + degrees + " " + altitude + units;


   }


}
```

Here is the class with the main method I was using just to test this class.

```
public class WaterState 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Water timWater = new Water(-100, "C", 1000, "Ft");


    String newWater = timWater.getState();
    System.out.println(newWater);

    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you [just post this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24500517/2970947)?

Comment: i suppose you should once review your logic by yourself , before asking it here

Comment: i have reviewed it. that is why i am asking it here. obviously there is something i am missing/not understanding

Comment: A simple step would be to reduce your calculations to a single unit, converting from the other first.  Then you simply have a single set of calculations to perform...

Comment: and previously I realized I was having issues with just figuring out how to do the calculations correctly. I thought I had that figured out, but now it keeps returning that it is a gas when it shouldn't. I'm just not sure if I'm calculating something wrong or what?

Comment: I would get out your debugger and verify the `bpFeet` and `bpMeters`, because I'm not sure that the boiling point has any relationship to the temp...

Comment: thanks madprogrammer. I think you are right.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I needed to use the standard BP of 212 F and 99.98 C instead of the user input temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The problem area is the following code:

You should check the calculation.

```
bpFeet = temperature - (altitude * 0.001); // boiling point given an altitude in feet
        bpMeters = temperature - (altitude * 0.01); // boiling point given an altitude in meters
```

No matter what you put in temperature, the bpFeet will always be less, hence when you are doing a comparison `if (temperature >= bpFeet)` it will always return true hence making the water as gaseous.

Comment: thanks for the help. I actually realized that earlier. I put a comment, but I probably should have put it as an answer

Comment: You could simply add `if degrees.equals("C")` and then some kind of boiling point variable for degrees in celsius and similar for degrees F and just use that instead of temperature